# Is there a way for an object to know if it is contained in another object?

Tags: java, composition

My specific problem is I have a class A that contains another class B. B contains some numbers and A contains the total of these numbers. What I like to do is when the numbers change in B, it should let class A know that it updated its numbers so that A updates its own numbers.

To give you an example, let's say B contains:

number1 = 7;
number2 = 5;

so A contains 12.

Now when I change 7 to 9, A should contain 14.

What would the best practice be?

PS: It is not only about A contains B, in fact I have D contains C, C contains A and A contains B.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two alternatives:

- Don't store the total in `A`, compute it on demand.

  ```
  class A {
      B b;

      ...

      public int getTotal() {
          return b.getNumber1() + b.getNumber2();
      }
  }
  ```
- Or, let `A` be an observer and listen for changes in `B`.

  ```
  class A implements ChangeListener {
      B b;
      int total = 0;

      public A() {
          b = new B();
          b.addChangeListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
          // recompute total
      }
  }
  ```

  this approach is usually referred to as the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Well aiobe thanks for your answer, but I need to compute it. Because it is a good optimization for our web service, this is in fact a report design and it should be computed once and the results should be read-only.

Comment: Which one of my two suggestions doesn't fit?

Comment: well the first one doesn't work, I apologize for rushing on commenting. I am looking into the second method now. Is ChangeListener an java api interface or should I implement it myself?

Comment: User `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener` or write your own. It typically contains a single method :-)

Comment: I'd rather use `a java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`: there's no reason to tie a generic bean to Swing.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use the `Publisher-Subscriber` patter, **commonly** known as `Observer Pattern`.

**2.** It can be also done by **creating a thread polling the variable's value**, any changes done will be handled in the way prescribed by you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Observer Pattern.